# keyCode and which are deprecated - so why is that not working?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keyboard-events

According to [MDN Web Docs KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) and [Google Updates KeyboardEvent](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/keyboardevent-keys-codes) **key** and **code** are implemented while **keyCode** and **which** are deprecated.

With that in mind I should be able to dispatch `keydown` event as below:

```
document.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
        key: 'K',
        code: 'KeyK',
        shiftKey: false,
        ctrlKey: false,
        metaKey: false
    })
);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work whilst if I add **keyCode** additionally this script works perfectly. Object with keyCode:

```
document.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
        key: 'K',
        code: 'KeyK',
        keyCode: 75,
        shiftKey: false,
        ctrlKey: false,
        metaKey: false
    })
);
```

Am I missing something? **keyCode** and **which** are deprecated so it should be possible to create working event without these elements. I cannot find anywhere answer for that.

I am using current version of Google Chrome (87). I test this script by sending <kbd>k</kbd> key to YouTube for play/pause video.

Comment: maybe their code is looking for keyCode and not key....

Comment: Dispatching a `keydown` event doesn't actually trigger a keydown on the keyboard.

Comment: @epascarello make sens. If they added key and code a while ago, I thought they also improved the youtube code since keycode is deprecated.

Comment: You would need to talk to their developers ;) deprecated stuff does not disappear. It is sort of like someone saying "Don't do that" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "deprecated" status in the documentation is telling you that you shouldn't rely on those attributes being present *in events which you receive*, because *the browser developers* are planning to stop including them *in events which they create*.

However, in this case, you are simulating the part of the code that the *browser* would normally perform, in *creating* the event. Neither you nor the browser has any way to know what the code *receiving* that event is going to look for.

If you leave out the deprecated attributes, you are emulating a *future* browser, and the YouTube site you're testing on might not currently be ready to work with that future browser. You are better off setting all the attributes a *current* browser would set for that event.

Note that the developers of YouTube, while ultimately employed by the same company as the developers of Chrome, likely have very little connection. They will be updating their code to follow current best practices on a regular basis *like any well-run development team*, but that takes time, and has to be prioritised amongst everything else they're working on.